# How to access first element of JSON object array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I exptect that mandrill_events only contains one object. How do I access its `event-property`?

```
var req = { mandrill_events: '[{"event":"inbound","ts":1426249238}]' }
```

Comment: That's a string, not an object. You'd need to parse the string into an object first with `JSON.parse(str)`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript

Comment: `JSON.parse(req[mandrill_events])[0].event` will return `"inbound"`.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl or not .. `JSON.parse(req.mandrill_events)[0]["event"]` would

Comment: @Hacketo: Yeah I forgot to remove the brackets...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To answer your titular question, you use `[0]` to access the first element, but as it stands `mandrill_events` contains a string not an array, so `mandrill_events[0]` will just get you the first character, '['.

So either correct your source to:

```
var req = { mandrill_events: [{"event":"inbound","ts":1426249238}] };
```

and then `req.mandrill_events[0]`, or if you're stuck with it being a string, parse the JSON the string contains:

```
var req = { mandrill_events: '[{"event":"inbound","ts":1426249238}]' };
var mandrill_events = JSON.parse(req.mandrill_events);
var result = mandrill_events[0];
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that `[` is returned as content if the variable is string, not object

Answer (score 45):

```
var req = { mandrill_events: '[{"event":"inbound","ts":1426249238}]' }

console.log(Object.keys(req)[0]);
```

Make any Object array (`req`), then simply do `Object.keys(req)[0]` to pick the first key in the Object array.

Comment: While answers are always welcome, including a brief explanation of *how* the code solves the problem is more helpful to others. It also reduces the likelihood the post will end up in the "Very-Low-Quality" queue (as this one did).

Comment: Your answer helped me out, but one thing that should be noted is that `Object.keys(req)[0]` will return you the id of the object in that array, so to get the actual value you need: `mandrill_events[Object.keys(req)[0]].event`

Comment: and how do I get the value using this code?

Comment: `event` and `ts`?

Answer (score 7):

I'll explain this with a general example:

```
var obj = { name: "John", age: 30, city: "New York" };
var result = obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]];
```

The result variable will have the value "John"

Answer (score 6):

the event property seems to be string first you have to parse it to json :

```
 var req = { mandrill_events: '[{"event":"inbound","ts":1426249238}]' };
 var event = JSON.parse(req.mandrill_events);
 var ts =  event[0].ts
```

Answer (score 1):

`'[{"event":"inbound","ts":1426249238}]'` is a string, you cannot access any properties there. You will have to parse it to an object, with `JSON.parse()` and then handle it like a normal object

Answer (score 0):

After you parse it with Javascript, try this:

```
mandrill_events[0].event
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming thant the content of `mandrill_events` is an object (not a string), you can also use `shift()` function:

```
var req = { mandrill_events: [{"event":"inbound","ts":1426249238}] };
var event-property = req.mandrill_events.shift().event;
```