# Error while executing soapUI

Tags: selenium, jmeter, soapui

This is the code I am executing:

```
 import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
   def response= messageExchange.response.responseContent
   def jsonsl= new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)
   log.info jsonsl.results(0).id
   log.info jsonsl.results(0).houseName
```

Error:

```
No signature of method: groovy.json.internal.LazyMap.results() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [0] Possible solutions: values(), values(), equals(java.lang.Object), equals(java.lang.Object), equals(java.lang.Object), equals(java.util.Map
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that you showed up:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def response= messageExchange.response.responseContent
def jsonsl= new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)
log.info jsonsl.results(0).id
log.info jsonsl.results(0).houseName
```

You need to change some minor things like your brackets composition are wrong it should be like:

```
log.info jsonsl.results[0].id
log.info jsonsl.results[0].houseName
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are trying to get first element in results array: `jsonsl.results(0).id`

The way to [access first element in json array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29032525/how-to-access-first-element-of-json-object-array) is by `[]` brackets:

```
log.info jsonsl.results[0].id
log.info jsonsl.results[0].houseName
```